# Дополнительно меню (кнопки) администратора

Tags: python, telegram-bot

**Как сделать чтобы у администратора показывалось в боте дополнительное меню (добавилось к стандартному), а у пользователя показывалось стандартное?**

```
#Стандартное меню:

keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
keyboard.row(KEYBOARD['FOR_A_LAST'], KEYBOARD['FOR_A_FIRST'])
keyboard.row(KEYBOARD['FOR_A_PHONE'], KEYBOARD['FOR_A_FULL'])
keyboard.row(KEYBOARD['FOR_A_DATAR'], KEYBOARD['DATAR_R'])
keyboard.row(KEYBOARD['FOR_SUBSY'], KEYBOARD['FOR_SUBSN'], KEYBOARD['FOR_A_HELP'])

#Меню администратора:  

admin = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
admin.row(KEYBOARD['MESS_DR'], KEYBOARD['MESS'])
admin.row(KEYBOARD['IMPORT'], KEYBOARD['LOGS'])
admin.row(KEYBOARD['ADD_ID'], KEYBOARD['REBOOT']

#Старт  

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message):
    name = message.chat.first_name + ' ' + (message.chat.last_name or '')
    msg = f"Привет {name} . \n"

    if message.chat.id == settings.ADMINS_ID:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=msg, reply_markup=admin, parse_mode='HTML')
    
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=msg, reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message):
    name = message.chat.first_name + ' ' + (message.chat.last_name or '')
    msg = f"Привет {name} . \n"
    keyboard=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    if message.chat.id == settings.ADMINS_ID:
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="admin button"))
    else:
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="userbutton"))

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=msg, reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML')
```